ModuleNotFoundError for module in different folder
when I have this folder structure

mod1 contains a function
def mymod():
    return 5

mod2.py has
from d1.mod1 import mymod

print(mymod)

Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'd1'
I also tried doing sys.path.insert
Seems so simple and Ive been tearing my hair out.
VS Code recognises the imports
Thanks

it seems you execute mod2.py directly which means the project path is PYLAB/d2. there's not d1 module here, which is actually under PYLAB, parent folder of d2.
to solve this, you can add the path of folder where d1 is in, which is PYLAB(or d2/..).
mod2.py
# add the folder where d1 module is in to sys path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# "os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))" means "mod2.py -> d2 -> PYLAB"

from d1.mod1 import mymod

print(mymod)


"VS Code recognises the imports" because you open PYLAB and VSCode recognize this folder as root folder(/project path) when it anaylize your code syntx.
if you have a py file(let's say test.py) under PYLAB and call mod2.py in test.py. from d1.mod1 import mymod in mod2.py can work if you directly execute test.py

Thanks for this and for the clear explanantion. It works now
